# Unable to build WiX 3.10 project in TFS 2015

Tags: tfs, wix, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I am using TFS 2015 trail version in windows server 2012.I created windows service project in  visual studio community edition along with WiX Project to package the windows service. If i build the solution from visual studio, I am able to get the MSI. But if i use Visual studio build in TFS 2015,i get the following error.

> "Unexpected exit code received from msbuild.exe: 1" and  "Task VSBuild
>   failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for
>   more details."

I refered the below links as  reference :
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/wix_with_team_build.html-
http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/msbuild/daily_builds.html

1) I am unable to follow the first link steps as i got struck in step 2:
i am unable to find configuration folder in build definition.
I was reading that we do not have TFSBuild.proj straing from TFS version 2010.

> "Right-click on the Build Definition and select View Configuration
>   Folder." "Check out and open the file named TFSBuild.proj."

2)I am unable to follow second link as well. I am getting below error:

> "The imported project "C:\wix\3.8\Wix.targets" was not found. Confirm
>   that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the
>   file exists on disk."

since I am new to TFS Build 2015, any help or guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using NuGet to install Wix packages. If so, you need to create one build.proj to restore these packages during build: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with NuGet 2.7, the NuGet Visual Studio extension integrates into Visual Studio's build events and restores missing packages when a build begins. This feature is enabled by default. If you are using NuGet to install Wix packages, that's why you can get a successful build from visual studio.

If you want to use NuGet to install Wix packages, you can create one build.proj to restore these packages during build. Check: http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build

If you don't use NuGet to install Wix packages, a traditional way you can refer to:http://edwinfrey.com/blog/2012/06/11/building-wix-msis-in-tfs-preview/

Comment: Thanks Cece  for reply. I am not using MSBuild  to build. I am using visual studio build in TFS 2015.What can be done for Visual studio build.?

Comment: If you copy your project to TFS build agent machine and use VS to build it, can you get a successful build?

Comment: Yes ..if i copy our project to TFS build agent machine and use VS to build ,it, build is succedded

Comment: Could you share the detailed logs for the "Task VSBuild failed"?